# Remember me with SharedPreferences works slow in android. How to make it work faster?

Tags: android, remember-me

In android, i did remember me function with SharedPreferences. Like this

```
 if (futuristicLoginLayoutBinding.checkboxLogin.isChecked()) {
                                        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("checkbox", MODE_PRIVATE);
                                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                                        editor.putString("remember", "true");
                                        editor.apply();
                                        Toast.makeText(context, "Girişi xatırla seçildi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    } else if (!futuristicLoginLayoutBinding.checkboxLogin.isChecked()) {
                                        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("checkbox", MODE_PRIVATE);
                                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                                        editor.putString("remember", "false");
                                        editor.apply();
                                        Toast.makeText(context, "Girişi xatırla seçilmədi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
```

But when "Remember me" is selected, login layout will show for about 0.1-0.3 seconds the next time the app is opened. )) Like this [problematic login image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnetS.jpg)

How can I make it faster so that the user doesn't see the login page for about 0.2 seconds

Comment: where is this function ?? in you mainActivity ??

Comment: in my loginactivity.  In  firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword method, before Intent to main activity i check it

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing the preference multiple time. Initialize it global then check,  like in your activity class

```
  SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("checkbox", MODE_PRIVATE);

 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
```

now use the object inside your method where you are doing the operation i.e, preference and editor.

Comment: Thank you, i fixed it.  But still same, i can still see login layout (

Comment: Ok. One more way you can try. Design a splash screen  and put your check user logic in splash Activity. Here you can check if user is already logged in with remember me option redirect to home screen or any screen as per by your flow else redirect to login screen. In that meantime you can show a loader with a message like validating please wait etc.